# Are there any efficient algorithems to find packets similarities in a list?

Tags: machine-learning, trees, real-time

I would like to make a program which finds similar packets (there might be more then one class of similarity) in packet list (which is updated all the time). Are there any efficient algorithems to find these similarities?

By similarities I mean that they have the same size, type and payload.

I thought about using tree(with conditions on the branches just like  decision tree) or vector support machine with k classes (k>2), but it means that it should have a lot of classes/nodes. Say there are 10 different packets and 2 kinds of similar packets (3 packets in each group). Then there will be 10 classes with single packet, 2 classes with 3 packets - So its size depends on the amount of packets which can be really big.

thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by similarity?  How would you like to measure similarity?  There are many possible ways one could do it.  Small edit distance?  Contains a large byte sequence in common?  Something else?

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible approaches for measuring document similarity:

- [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)
- [shingling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling)
- [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)
- TF-IDF and cosine similarity
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/101569/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8897593/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/29842137/781723

I suggest you think more about what metric makes sense for you, and review the literature on information retrieval and natural language processing to see what metrics have been used in other contexts.

Comment: I read about these algorithems, but  is not them slow algorithems (for example, it is expensive to create the shingles in the w-shingles algorithem). and I have to find all the similarities in the list

Comment: @AdiMl, if you knew about an approach and had rejected it for some reason, it would be good to mention it in the question, so we don't waste our time telling you something you already know; and to make sure to state the explicit requirement that the approach you rejected violates.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  But I don't follow you; w-shingling is very fast.  If you're finding it slow, maybe you haven't quite understood how to implement it (?), or maybe you have a different definition of slow.  Either way, I encourage you to edit the question to clear this up.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question what I rejected. I am sorry, this algorithem looked slow to me, but I don't quite know this algorithem, so I believe to you saying it is fast and will try it myself. thanks again.